# How to ignore all .sass-cache folders in my project via .gitignore

Tags: git, sass

id like to igone all .sass-cache (sass cach folder) via .gitignore file in a single line

looking for line like :

```
/**/*/.sass-cache
```

its possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure:

```
.sass-cache/
```

should be enough to exclude all files within directories called `.sass-cache` in the whole subtree where the `.gitignore` is present.

But be aware that git ignore feature only works on untracked files. If you have already files in those folders tracked, you have to delete them from the repository, e. g. with `git rm --cached ...` and a commit.